# how to use existing vue project found github

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vuejs2, web-deployment

I found this example vue project in github. 
How do i deploy it in my localhost ?

https://github.com/vuejs-example-apps/tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 2):

No installation required. Vue is used as a CDN in that project and all you need are

- corssCircle.html
- crossCircle.js and
- crossCircle.css

If you are going to deploy it on your localhost, simply rename the `corssCircle.html` into `index.html` for xampp, etc. or you can just open the file in browser and it will start running.

Answer (score 1):

If you open crossCircle.html you'll see that Vue is included via this line:
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`
If you would like to install Vue locally you can check this guide for [options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html).